# Словил Kernel Panic при обновлении Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Сделал `do-release-upgrade`, всё вроде обновилось. При обновлении sshd_config возник конфликт между уже установленной версией и новой, предлагаемой обновлением. Зашёл посмотреть, что там в отличиях файла, а выйти не смог. В итоге сделал kill screen (кнопка x) и вышел в основную консоль. Сделал `apt-get update`, всё работало нормально. Сделал reboot и теперь система не загружается. В VNC-консоли такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Изначально я сумел найти [ответ на этот вопрос](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407058/kernel-panic-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-an-unknown-block) на англоязычном StackExchange. Однако решить я проблему сумел таким образом, что в качестве 3 шага я ввёл команду:

`dpkg --configure -a`

И установка продолжилась, установив необходимую версию linux-ядра и все необходимые зависимости.